# The first letter of the output text disappears with subsequent iterations

Tags: c#

Please help me figure out why the first letter of the output text disappears after the 2nd and subsequent iterations

```
public static void Main()
{
  OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

  int playersNumber = 0;
  string? name;
  while (true)
  {
    Console.Write($"Write your name, player #{playersNumber}: ");
    string possibleName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("You confirm your choice?");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("press ENTER for YES");
    Console.WriteLine("press ESC for REWRITE");

    char choice = (char)Console.ReadKey().Key;

    if (choice == (char)ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
      name = possibleName;
      return;
    }
    if (choice == (char)ConsoleKey.Escape)
    {
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: its to do with your choice of using esc key to reenter the name, change it to any other key and its fine

Comment: It should be mentioned that hitting the ESC key is how to trigger the problem. @pm100 I'd say the question is not about *which key to use*, it is about why this happens and/or how to fix it while using ESC.

Comment: Console.ReadKey has an overload where you may pass a boolean variable as true to suppress the output of the key to the console window. Not tested, but I suppose that could fix the problem

Comment: can confirm that `ReadKey(true)` works with the ESC key - here is code of the call https://source.dot.net/#System.Console/System/Console.cs,efb6e25dbfd5b304

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a happening because when you press esc you are also typing it into the cmd. So it ends up esc the first char in the next printed string.

so your choice line should look like this to capture the esc press.

```
char choice = (char)Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
```

ReadKey as an override passing in a bool called intercept.

> Parameters
> intercept (bool) Determines whether to display the pressed
> key in the console window. true to not display the pressed key;
> otherwise, false.

[Microsoft Docs For ReadKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=net-7.0#system-console-readkey(system-boolean))